# Laravel firstOrCreate() not working with event listeners

Tags: php, laravel, events, listener, laravel-9

I have a table "phones" with columns "id" and "number". I need to store only unique phone numbers.

I used to do this:

```
$phone = Phone::firstOrCreate(['number' => $phone['number']]);
```

And it worked just fine.

Now I want to save phone numbers without spaces, but show them with spaces for better reading. So I created two event listeners and registered them in Phone model like this:

```
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'saving' => \App\Events\Phone\PhoneSavingEvent::class,
    'retrieved' => \App\Events\Phone\PhoneRetrievedEvent::class,
];
```

With listeners defines like this:

```
public function handle(PhoneSavingEvent $event)
{
    $event->phone->number = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $event->phone->number);
}
```

```
public function handle(PhoneRetrievedEvent $event)
{
    $event->phone->number = wordwrap($event->phone->number, 3, ' ', true);
}
```

Listeners works just fine. Phone numbers are saved without spaces and displayed with spaces. But function firstOrCreate() now saves duplicate phone numbers to database.

How can I save unique phone numbers again with these two listeners?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

If I don't use `$dispatchesEvents` but use this code instead:

```
protected static function booted()
{
    static::saving(function ($phone) {
        $phone->number = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $phone->number);
    });
}
```

The firstOrCreate() function works well, when trying to save number without spaces (like "111222333"). It will find that in database and won't save duplicate.

But if I try to save number with spaces (like "111 222 333") the firstOrCreate() function save it like "111222333", but that number is already in database.

I probably should treat the number somewhere else than in event listener. But where/how?

Comment: use validation rule unique so you can avoid storing this

Comment: Well I simply cannot remove spaces from number just before saving, but much sooner. I will probably create model function like Phone::save_unique($phone) and will use this to treat the number and check for duplicates. Anyway thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this link https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators

And add `$table->string('number')->unique();` to your migration.

You can use these rules to validate your number format and make sure that it is unique
`'number' => 'required|numeric|min:8|max:11|unique:your_table_name'`

Comment: Ha! Accessors & Mutators. That is what I'm looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

hey you need to set your number column unique attribute in you migration

```
 $table->string('number')->unique();
```

in your controller before try to manage data check and validate data first the simple way like this below or you can check with regex to

```
'number' => 'required|numeric|min:8|max:11',
```

and in your `dispatchesEvents` variable you can use `creating` instead of `saving`

Comment: Thank you. But I don't want validation to stop me. I want if somebody will try to save number that is already in database, it will appear to him, that this number has been saved without any validation error displayed. I am using "saving" because it is called when both creating and updating. If I set the "number" field as unique, I just end up with "Integrity constraint violation"